# Facing Permission Issue in Android version 33

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions, android-version

**We have using following android permissions in androidManifeast.xml file.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"
    tools:ignore="DuplicateUsesFeature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.intent.category.MASTER_CLEAR.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="SystemPermissionTypo" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_*" />
```

All the above mentioned permissions are granted eventhough we are getting the permission not granted alert message with below mentioned points.We don't know how to resolve this and proceed further.

Redirecting.
1.To access camera and stroeage for the QR code scanning.
2.To read phone state to collect the device information while login.
3.Let appM stay connected in the background.

We need to accept permission android latest versions.

[image]

Comment: is this old project and you are updating after 3-5 years?